# Are electromechanical oscillators still in use? Or totally obsolete?

Tags: ac, oscillator, generator

An electromechanical oscillator is basically an AC generator that has a much wider frequency range. I read something on a wikipedia article about a radio frequency AC generator used for military radio transmission around the turn of the 20th century. The interest comes from developing an oscillator that has very low frequency(10 to 30 Hz)and could produce an output power of at least 100kW and even into the megawatts. It would be essentially a low frequency AC generator.

Comment: If you're asking this question, this problem is at least 10 years outside of your skillset.

Comment: 25 Hz AC power was used in Eastern Canada and the US Northeast in the early 1900s, and 40 or 42Hz was used in some other areas - look on Wikipedia for "Utility Frequency" for details.  Current AC power plants use mechanical generators to produce 50 Hz or 60 Hz AC power.

Comment: What use is it?  Generating that much power is easier than getting it into a suitable antenna.   Lowest frequencies in common use are 457 kHz (avalanche locators).

Comment: I think you have been beaten to it - they are just called power generators.  At 50Hz your wavelength is 6000 km - that is just a bit more than the distance between New York and London. Then there's the interference due to all the other utility companies around the world producing power at the same sort of frequencies and lets not forget the s-l-o-w--d-a-t-a--r-a-t-e at those 'carrier' frequencies.

Comment: There was the Clam Lake(WI) Naval ELF transmitter that was used for submarine communications and had a CW frequency of 76Hz. I believe there were 2 14-mile long antennas extending in opposite directions from the transmitting station. To get enough power to communicate with subs you would need a VERY high amplitude/power CW oscillator. So I am going to guess they used a massive rotary converter to produce a monophase 76Hz AC signal.

Comment: Lool up radio station  SAQ Grimeton. It transmits at 17.2 kHz and has a still working Alexanderson generator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing an Alexanderson alternator, 1920s technology for generating significant power in the < 100 kHz (Note, kHz not Hz!) range for long wave radio transmission.

These things had many, many, poles and were run at scarily high shaft speeds but at the time vacuum tubes were only good to low kW power levels, where the alternators could make hundreds of kW.

There is still an example in Sweden that was in use up to the 1990s for submarine communications, it is still fired up occasionally and can be heard on the air.

There are youtube videos of the thing being spun up.

For shits and giggles I have actually built a mechanically driven direct conversion receiver, I used a stepper motor as the alternator driven by a servo motor, the stepper driving a diode ring mixer into an amplified speaker, mostly because I wanted to try to hear the Alexanderson set on a mechanical receiver (I cheated and used saturating ferrite cores as a frequency multiplier so I did not have to drive the thing at really stupid speeds).
CW tone was not wonderful but it was there and I could copy it.

Comment: SAQ at Grimeton still has a few transmissions every year.